# How to link a Part from an RCP App to SWTBot?

Tags: unit-testing, eclipse-rcp, swtbot

I am starting to use SWTBot to test my application Eclipse RCP v4.

This is my code, to get a part via an id and activate it.

```
protected static void openPart(final String id) {
    Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            EPartService partService = E4Workbench.getServiceContext().getActiveLeaf().get(EPartService.class);
            MPart part = partService.findPart(id);
            partService.activate(part);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my tests. And it doesn't work...

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    openPart("testmaker.part.gauche");
    bot.tree().getTreeItem("hju / PQT").expand();
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    openPart("testmaker.part.stepRightSide");
    bot.button("Add Comment").click();
}
```

I don't know how to link my `private static SWTBot bot;` with my RCP Part.

I have already tried with `bot.viewby...(name/id/etc).show();`, it doesn't work.

This is my RCP application :

[image]

Does anyone can help me to use an rcp app with SWTBot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution now.

With the `org.eclipse.swtbot.e4.finder` plugin and the class SWTWorkbenchBot from this plugin it works.